# How do I change the breadcrumbs title and url from blog to news in PyroCMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, pyrocms

Excuse me everybody. 
I am new to PyroCMS, but I'm trying to learn it. 
I want to ask about how to change the breadcumbs title, url and texts from blog into news in the blog module. But without changing the core of the blog module, i mean blog text (url, title, breadcumbs, etc.) that is on the front end only.
If anyone knows how to do this it would be much appreciated :)

*If there is someone who doesn't understand this question, ask me.

Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
$this->template->set_breadcrumb('test')
$this->template->set_breadcrumb('test', '/module/some-page')
```

For more details: Please check this forum:

https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/10524/custom-breadcrumb-items-from-inside-a-module

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I mean all of blog texts changed into news, at all. even in admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the URI in `system/cms/config/routes.php` and route 'news' to 'blog'. Take care to not override the default and admin routes.

Everything else can be overridden in your theme:

- Create a `modules/blog` folder into your `theme/views` folder
- Copy everything except the admin folder from `system/cm/modules/blog/views` into your newly created folder
- Edit away, meaning change all occurances of `blog` to `news`

If you're using the blogs plugin or widgets, you might also have to override those. Check them out and look for blog URIs. Copy the widgets or plugins, rename them to `news`or whatever and use your custom plugins instead of the standard blog ones.

This way you'll have everything in your theme, with maybe a custom widget or custom plugin here and there. But no changes in the core.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system/cms/modules/blog/language/english/blog_lang.php` and `system/cms/modules/blog/details.php` and change all the values where it says "Blog" to "News".

This requires changing module files. The only other way is to clone the whole module to the addons directory and change the same files.